# VBA script in Excel to populate the .from field from a cell in the worksheet

Tags: vba, email, excel, cdo.message

I have sucessfully configured a VBA script based on an example from http://www.rondebruin.nl to send a copy of an active worsheet in excel as an attachment using a gmail account and CDO.

What I would like to modify is the ability to alter the .From field with the email address of the user that fills out the spreadsheet.  The email address will be filled in the spreadsheet as a part of the process.  Right now, I can only have the .From field populate with a hard coded email address or the email address of the SMTP account being used to send the attachment.

Is my idea possible?

Here is my code as of now.

```
Option Explicit


'This procedure will send the ActiveSheet in a new workbook
'For more sheets use : Sourcewb.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3")).Copy

Sub CDO_Mail_ActiveSheet_Or_Sheets()
'Working in 97-2007
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
Dim Destwb As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim iMsg As Object
Dim iConf As Object
Dim Flds As Variant

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

'Copy the ActiveSheet to a new workbook
ActiveSheet.Copy

'Or if you want to copy more then one sheet use:
'Sourcewb.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3")).Copy

Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
With Destwb
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007
        'We exit the sub when your answer is NO in the security dialog that you only
        'see  when you copy a sheet from a xlsm file with macro's disabled.
        If Sourcewb.Name = .Name Then
            With Application
                .ScreenUpdating = True
                .EnableEvents = True
            End With
            MsgBox "Your answer is NO in the security dialog"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
            Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If .HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            End Select
        End If
    End If
End With

'    'Change all cells in Destwb to values if you want
'    For Each sh In Destwb.Worksheets
'        sh.Select
'        With sh.UsedRange
'            .Cells.Copy
'            .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'            .Cells(1).Select
'        End With
'        Application.CutCopyMode = False
'    Next sh
'    Destwb.Worksheets(1).Select


'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it
TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
TempFileName = "FRAT 135 Helo" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
'TempFileName = "Part of " & Sourcewb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

With Destwb
    .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    .Close savechanges:=False
End With

Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
Set Flds = iConf.Fields
With Flds
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "xxx@testsite.net"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    .Update
End With


With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf
    .To = "safety@xxxx.net"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    'I tried this but it doesn't work
    '.From = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D5").Value

    .From = """Insert Name Here"" <test@yahoo.com>"
    .Subject = "FRAT 135 Helo Submission"
    .TextBody = "Hi There"
    .HTMLBody = "<H3><B>Dear Safety Advisor</B></H3>" & _
                 "The attached spreadsheet has been submitted by a member of your team.<BR>" & _
                "Please view this and respond as needed"
                '"<A HREF=""http://www.companywebsite.com"">Corporate Website</A>"
    .AddAttachment TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
    .Send
End With


'Delete the file you have send
Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible. Anything you can hard-code can be replaced with a variable value.

You just have to make sure the data that you are reading from the sheet is in the correct format.

You can use the following to make sure you are getting a valid value from the sheet:

```
Sub EmailFrom()
    Dim hardCodedFrom As String
    Dim fromField As String

    hardCodedFrom = """Insesrt Name Here"" <test@yahoo.com>"
    fromField = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D5").Value
    MsgBox "The hard-coded .From email is " & hardCodedFrom & vbCrLf & _
            "The variable .From email is " & fromField
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't get the .From field to work but your example worked and I can manipulate the code to put the excel filled email address in the body of the email sent out.  Not ideal but it will work.

I don't think you can update the .From field...as many times I have tried, even with the example above it will only change the "Name" of who it is coming from but always use the actual address of the smtp server it was routed through.  Maybe I am missing something but I feel better trying your example.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: That makes sense, although if that's the case, I wouldn't think you could hard-code the value.